# Phantom ways showing in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js

I have a puzzling shape rendering in my maps, which does not seem to be in the OSM data.

This way https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/22871271 looks fine on OSM/Mapnik, nothing weird shows up in the data layer.

The same location in mapbox studio, displays a number of overlapping ways which were removed ages ago, and they render in my maps (https://maps.unimelb.edu.au/parkville/building/148). I have noticed the problem for a couple of months, and republished the style several times since, and have seen other edited features show up in less than a day, so it's not just a passing glitch.

The most obvious stray way is a pedestrian road, named "Professor's Ct". I'm not a super user of OSM data, but I tried to find it using overpass turbo to no avail. I don't think it's there, but Mapbox Studio begs to differ.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: OK, this is getting annoying. These phantom items are still showing up. They show up in all versions of Mapbox data, they even show up in Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like MapBox' database missed the update where the overlapping ways have been removed. This can happen if there had been a temporary problem with the diffs and no full re-import did occur. In that case some intermediate updates are lost but newer updates still get included.

Touching the ways in OSM or undeleting and deleting the ways again might resolve the issue. But this would be just a bad workaround, ideally the database at MapBox needs to get fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is pretty much what I expected. Hadn't thought of undeleting - don't even know when the changeset would have happened. Might go searching the history :-)

Comment: hmm 12 months back, and I haven't uncovered the changesets - definitely time to get MB to tweak their database :-)